# Delete function does not work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with a delete function. I did the following:

Set up routes:

```
resources :todos do
 member do 
  delete :destroy_all
 end
end
```

Set up a link the index.html.erb

```
  <%= link_to "Delete last seven days", destroy_all_todo_path(@todos), class: 'btn btn-success', method: :delete %>
```

And have defined the following method in my controller:

```
def destroy_all
 @todo = Todo.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 7.days).destroy_all
if @todo.destroy
 flash[:notice] = "Your old todos are deled!"
else
 flash[:error] = "There was an error!"
end
```

But when I try to run it I get the erro: undefined method `destroy' for []:Array

Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

Comment: Try to imagine what `if @todo.destroy` does after you've already run `destroy_all`. What value is in `@todo`? I think it should be clear that the `if` statement here doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
@todo = Todo.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 7.days).destroy_all
```

destroys all the models and return you an array of records which has been deleted. Then you call `destroy` on that array.

In general, you don't need to check if destroy_all succeeded, at least I never had a single case this failed. Just do:

```
def destroy_all
  Todo.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 7.days).destroy_all
  flash.now[:notice] = "Your old todos are deled!"
end
```

If you still prefer to have a fallback, add a rescue statement - destroy will never return you false, it will succeed or raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

As @ptd noted in the comments, you are deleting the objects and then trying to delete them again.  I would change your code to this:

```
def destroy_all
 @todos = Todo.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 7.days)
if @todos.destroy_all
 flash[:notice] = "Your old todos are deled!"
else
 flash[:error] = "There was an error!"
end
```

While this code will work, @BroiSatse's answer is better because checking that `if` statement against an empty array doesn't accomplish anything useful.